# Loading local image and html on WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have a local image and URL that contain HTML and CSS.

I am looking for a way to display on WkWebview like my poor drawing showing.

My initial thought was 1) WkWebview.load(URL) and 2) inject a local image via javascript but not sure this is possible.

In case of URL is not available, I still need to show the local image only.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please can you show use what you already tried

Comment: Can't you just use 2 different views on vertical stack, one containing the local image and other containing the html code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @Namra Parmar's comment, I created storyboard, uiView, and vertical stack. And the vertical stack contains UIImageView and WkWebview